# Infinity loop with async function

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, async-await

I need to fetch data from server in infinity loop.
This code generates a reursion, is this correct way?

My code (code updated):

```
function pause(delay) { return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, delay)) }
async function fetchData( url, tries = 5 ) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    if ( !response.ok )
      throw new Error('Request error');

    const contentType = response.headers.get('content-type');
    if ( !contentType || !contentType.includes('application/json'))
      throw new TypeError('not a JSON')

    const jsonData = await response.json();
    return jsonData;
  } catch(err) {
    console.error('catch error:', err, 'tries left', tries);
    if ( tries == 0 ) throw new Error(err);
    await pause(1500);
    return fetchData( url, tries - 1 );
  }
}

function infinityLoop() {
  fetchData('test.json').then(d => {console.log(d); pause(1000).then( infinityLoop ); });
}
infinityLoop();
```

Comment: If you want a code review better post it to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: it's almost right, but you don't always return a value ... try `await pause(1500); return fetchData(url, tries - 1);`

Comment: Thank you for answer. This is prototype. So i want to know is that the right way.

Comment: by the way, just ran a version of your `infinityLoop` function removing the fetch, just using Promises, after over 10 million iterations, there was still no issue with recursion depth - so, as far as your question goes, the only recursive function with an issue was `fetchData`, but you fixed that with my answer (making my answer redundant) and concentrated on the function that, while maybe not written the best way, didn't actually have a problem at all

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make an async loop, make an async loop

```
async function asyncLoop() {
  while(true) {
    let data = await fetchData('test.json');
    await pause(1000)
  }
}
asyncLoop();
```

Comment: thank you. That's a good suggestion ) i think this is the right one. 
But i what to know, is the Promise make a real recursion, when return the result with resolve. So is there recursion?
```
function infinityLoop() {
  fetchData('test.json').then(d => {console.log(d); pause(1000).then( infinityLoop ); });
}
infinityLoop();
```

Comment: @BenerBeer because `await` flattens `then` call (so you don't have a callback), and `while` flattens the recursion

Comment: actually, there is no recursion in this code, so "while flattens the recursion" sounds odd (but I know what you mean)

Comment: @JaromandaX `await` flattens `pause(1000).then( infinityLoop )`(callback) into `await pause(1000); return await infinityLoop();`, and `while` flattens `return await infinityLoop()`(recursion) into `while(true)`

Comment: as I said, it sounded odd, but I know what you meant. I mean, the original OP's `infinityLoop` has absolutely no recursion depth issue, so ...

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to put a await modifier infront of the `fetchData()` within the `infinityLoop()` after that you only need to make the function async aswell.

Comment: that would make zero difference to the end result

Comment: @JaromandaX What are you talking about? If he keeps it like that he will get a Promise instead of the true values.

Comment: huh? `.then(d` ... can assure you `d` is NOT a promise - the issue is the `fetchData` function will not return a value if the first `fetch` fails

Comment: thank you, so something like this?
async function infinityLoop() {
  let d = await fetchData('test.json');
  console.log(d);
  await pause(1000);
  return infinityLoop();
}